# Travel to Switzerland with a multiple-entry Schengen visa

Tags: visas, europe, switzerland

My husband has a Schengen visa from the French consulate issued in 2012, multiple entry, valid till 2017. We visited France in 2012 for 12 days,
we visited Italy in 2013 for 11 days (no issues), now we want to visit Switzerland for 12 days using the same visa (still valid).

Will there be any problems ?

Comment: There's no problems as long as your visits do not add up to more than 90 days in any given 180 period.  12 days by themselves are totally fine.

Comment: What makes you concerned that there would be a problem?

Comment: Switzerland joined the Schengen area rather recently, but it did join.

Comment: @phoog: only if you count 2008 as rather recent!

Comment: @TonyK true, what I meant was "compared to most of the other members."